# outlook.office365.com IMAP SEARCH on BODY and TEXT recently stopped working

Tags: office365, exchange-server, imap

I have a PHP script which connects to outlook.office365.com using IMAP, and searches for some messages. The IMAP command I use is like this:

`SUBJECT "examplea" BODY "exampleb"`

This worked consistently well for several years. Sometime in the last several months the outlook.office365.com server began to return ZERO results for this type of search, with no errors or alerts. I did not make any changes to my PHP script in this time.

I have tested many different commands today. Other IMAP SEARCH criteria work, in isolation and combined, just not BODY and TEXT. Performing a search for the same keywords in the web interface finds several matches.

**How would I find out if support this feature (searching BODY text) has changed?**

UPDATE: Some search criteria that are part of the [IMAP spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) such as `NOT`, `OR` return `Unknown search criterion`, which indicates that there is at least some of the spec is not supported. `BODY` and `TEXT` do not return an error.

Comment: Did you resolve this? We have problems with outlook.office365.com that are difficult to identify too but something to do with a combination or TEXT and OR queries.

Comment: @Jivings I was lucky with the dataset I had, as the subject had other data that I was able to match on. I changed the IMAP search command to use SUBJECT instead of BODY, as it appeared that Outlook 365 had stopped supporting it.

Comment: That makes sense. I appear to have gotten it to work by breaking my queries down so I have 4 or less OR queries. Who knows why!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Microsoft is removing basic authentication in favor of oAuth 2.0 so that the login is completely managed by Microsoft thanks to access tokens. So if we want to get,update (and so on) emails we have to use Micosoft Graph APIs. Probably using these APIs could fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, I did see some articles by Microsoft that mention removing basic authentication. I wish they were clearer about exactly when they were removing it, because a date correlation would have made it much simpler to know that they were connected.